# How would I rewrite the following query as an inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I rewrite the following query as an inner join?

```
select person.person_last_name,person.birth_date, vip_acct_person.vip_ACCT_ID 
from person, vip_acct_person 
where vip_acct_person.person_id=person.person_id and person.birth_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval 57 year) 
order by person.birth_date;
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query will be

```
select person.person_last_name,person.birth_date, vip_acct_person.vip_ACCT_ID 
from person INNER JOIN vip_acct_person ON
 vip_acct_person.person_id=person.person_id and person.birth_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval 57 year) 
order by person.birth_date;
```

But you should also work with aliases

```
select p.person_last_name,p.birth_date, v.vip_ACCT_ID 
from person p INNER JOIN vip_acct_person v ON
 v.person_id=p.person_id and p.birth_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval 57 year) 
order by p.birth_date;
```